# Adding "prepared by" and "for company x" to author list on a technical report

Tags: titles

I'm preparing a technical report, and rather than just listing the authors I'd like for the report to say something like, "Prepared by so and so for company x".  (It doesn't have to be that exactly, just something to that effect.)

What's a nice way to list the authors in this way in Latex?  I'm sure there's a really simple way to do it.

Comment: `\author{Prepared by so and so for company x}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the standard commands `\title`, `\author`, `\date`, and `\maketitle` and possibly the [`titling`](http://www.ctan.org/titling) package to customize the appearance of the titling information. However, I'd suggest you to design your own `titlepage` from scratch. The simpler, the better, so you can say something like this:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{report}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand\PrepFor[1]{%
\par
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\textit{Prepared for}\par\bigskip
#1
\end{minipage}\par
}
\newcommand\PrepBy[1]{%
\par
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\textit{Prepared by}\par\bigskip
#1
\end{minipage}\par
}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\centering

\null\vfill
\vfill

{\bfseries\Large
This is the title for the report;\par it will span several lines\par
}

\vfill

\PrepFor{Some Name \\ Address Line 1 \\ Address Line 2}

\vfill

\PrepBy{Some Name \\ Address Line 1 \\ Address Line 2}

\vfill

\today

\vfill
\vfill

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

I just loaded the `showframe` package to have a visual guide of the text area.